# Different Applications for between Knapsack Without Reptition and Knapsack With Repetition

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I was wondering if there were situations which can be solved using only one or the other (i.e. only Knapsack with repetition or Knapsack without repetition), or if the two are always reducible to each other.

For the sake of clarification, we are given n items [1...n], with item i having weight w_i and value v_i, and are trying to select a combination of items such that the total value is maximized while the total weight stays less than some W.

The formulation of Knapsack without repetition (in terms of dynamic programming) is

```
K(w, j) = max{K(w-w_j, j-1) + v_j, K(w, j-1)}
```

where K(w, j) refers to the maximum value achievable using a knapsack of capacity k and items 1...j, while the formulation of knapsack with repetition is

```
K(w) = max{K(w-w_i) + v_i | w_i <= w}
```

where K(w) is the max achievable weight with a knapsack of capacity w.

Answer (score 0):

You can always reduce a knapsack with repetition to a knapsack without repetition but not the other way around. To reduce a knapsack with repetition to one without repetition simply add each object as many times as is the capacity of the knapsack. You can figure that you will never be able to fit more instances in the knapsack so the result will be the same as if having infinitely many copies.

To prove that the knapsack without repetition is not reducable to one with repetition, consider the following example:

You have 3 objects with price and weight respectively: (100$, 1kg), (10$, 2kg) and (20$, 3kg). Also imagine we can fit 3kg in our knapsack. If we allow repetition the best solution would be to take 3 objects of the first type, but without repetition the best solution is to take the first and the second object resulting in much smaller profit.